# What is the Fourier transform of $ f=\chi_{[-1,1]} $?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am totally new to Fourier transforms, so I would be very thankful for a feedback on my calculation. I want to calculate the Fourier transform of $ f=\chi_{[-1,1]} $, that is, $f(x)=1$ for $-1\le x\le 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

My answer:
\begin{align*}
\widehat{f}(\omega)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-i\omega x}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{1}{-i\omega}e^{-i\omega x}\right]_{-1}^1\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{-i\omega}\left(e^{-i\omega}-e^{i\omega}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{-i\omega}(-2i\sin \omega)\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{\omega} \sin \omega
\end{align*}
where I have used the relation
$$ \sin \omega = \frac{1}{2i} \left( e^{i\omega} - e^{-i\omega}\right). $$
Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct!${}$

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar. Thank you!

Comment: Your result is the **extremely important sine cardinal** function (name : "sinc"). Did you know it ?